# Is recommended to avoid save() restore()? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, performance, canvas, save, restore

I've read in many sites that using save() and restore() are the most (or near the most) heavy functions to process, so the question is, is better to manually restore the context state rather than using save() and restore()?

Example, which has better performance?:

```
ctx.save();
ctx.shadowColor = "black";
ctx.shadowOffsetX = 2; 
ctx.shadowOffsetY = 2; 
ctx.shadowBlur = 3;
ctx.textBaseline = "top";
ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10); // Any image
ctx.restore();
```

or

```
ctx.shadowColor = "black";
ctx.shadowOffsetX = 2; 
ctx.shadowOffsetY = 2; 
ctx.shadowBlur = 3;
ctx.textBaseline = "top";
ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10); // Any image
ctx.shadowColor = null;
ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0; 
ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0; 
ctx.shadowBlur = 0;
ctx.textBaseline = "alphabetic";
```

Basically i want to know if manually restoring all changed properties is better than using save() and restore(), even if there're several properties to restore manually.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I personally go against save/restore in many of my comments on questions here on SO because people don't seem to understand what it really does (stack **all** settable properties of your context). Often it is used to save just a single of these properties (often in a loop), so it makes sense to avoid using it. In your example, you are setting numerous of them, consumptive in their own (shadows...). So in **this** case, I wouldn't go against it a single second. Also note that if you were using clip, you would **have** to use it (or to reset the whole context). So it's a case by case situation.

Comment: Once you understand what it does, you can use it well, or do the best to avoid it as much as possible.

Answer (score 4):

### Looking at Save Restore Performance

Using save restore is generally slower than not using it. But this is highly variable and will depend on the hardware, the current state of the context and whether or not you use the restored state immediately after the restore, or continue without using the restored state.

Completely reinstating the context state manually will always be slower than the restore, as the restore does not have to recreate the state, it just moves memory.

When you have complex patterns, gradients, fonts, shadows set up, then save and restore can have significant performance impact. If you use save and restore you must be aware of what you are saving and if you need that state. For example if you set up a large pattern, then use save set a new fill and stroke style, then render, followed by restore and do not use the pattern you will have a slowdown as that pattern has to be reinstated even though it is not being used, which may mean the whole pattern bitmap being moved from RAM to GPU RAM (very slow)

**High quality profiling comparator tests**

Some raw dumps from a very accurate performance comparator profiler. Due to the nature of the canvas (shared hardware reliance I have two browsers open and ~12 Tabs plus 3 apps that all use the display) some results are classed as "fair" meaning that there is a significant variance in measured times. (Normally I would not use those results but I can not get them to stabilise)

> **NOTE** to be fair I wanted to run the tests on both Firefox and Chrome. Of late FF has had **much** better performance than Chrome. For this test I can not get chrome to run it. The test functions must come under 2ms for the tester to accept them. When I reduce the loop time (to an applauding 2) the test function never even makes it through stabilization time as it always ends with "Aw, Snap! Google Chrome ran out of memory while trying to display this webpage." I have tried many thing but can not get the tester to run on Chrome when I do anything with the 2D canvas.

All test are Firefox 50.0b1 (beta) with all flags at default. Sorry I could not get Chrome to work (Whasup chrome you're not looking good these days?)

Machine Win10 (32bit) CPU i7 Q720 @ 1.60GHz x64. 4G RAM. NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M (generic driver used)

---

**Test Direct transform restore V Save Restore**

The test code. (Note `ctx` is global)

```js
function saveRestore(){  // test function contains shared scope and array of test functions.
                         // Each test function is copied and wrapped in a performance timer (locally scoped)
                         // Times are for the internal context of the test functions 
                         // Use setTestFunctionCount(count) to set the number of unique copies of each test function to run. Default = 4 
// the content of this "sharedFunction" will be be placed in the same scope as the test functions. All test functions will use the same shared scope. The content of "sharedFunction" is not in strict mode. You may add the directive yourself 
  sharedFunction = function(){ 
     var i;
     var xdx = Math.cos(1);
     var xdy = Math.sin(1);
  }
  testFunctions = [{
          func:function(){
              for(i = 0; i < 1000; i ++){
                  ctx.save();
                  ctx.setTransform(xdx,xdy,-xdy,xdx,0,0);
                  ctx.restore();
              }            
          },
          name:"Save restore",
      },{
          func:function(){
              for(i = 0; i < 1000; i ++){
                  ctx.setTransform(xdx,xdy,-xdy,xdx,0,0);
                  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
             }},
          name:"Direct restore",
      }
  ];
  start();
}
```

The results. Note that the times are for the function, and each function iterates over the code of interest 1000  times. Hence the mean time (ie Direct restore  Mean : 316) means 0.316ms (1/1000th sec) to run the for loop 1000 times so each
`ctx.setTransform(xdx, xdy, -xdy, xdx, 0, 0); ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);.` takes about 0.000316ms to run. The loop time in this case is next to insignificant.

```
Test complete Results.
Calls per sec, % cycle time, % of best time
Direct restore : 3167 : 72.14% 100%.
Save restore : 1223 : 27.86% 38.61%

Total cycles : 1000
Stable cycles : 899 Total.
Tests per cycle : 65
Testing cycles stable for : 800 of 800 cycles 100.00%
Max test variance 10.468%
Test results are of fair quality. Should be run again.

List of all test function results. Mean times in micro secs
# calls, total time, mean time
--------------------
Test function : Save restore
7018 tests 5839.760ms Mean : 832
7020 tests 5715.160ms Mean : 814
7071 tests 5703.905ms Mean : 807
7028 tests 5748.850ms Mean : 818
Variance : 85.601micro sec. normalised : 10.468%
Ran : 28137 over 23007.675ms Mean : 817.702micro sec
--------------------
Test function : Direct restore
6905 tests 2184.580ms Mean : 316
7038 tests 2216.935ms Mean : 315
7061 tests 2230.390ms Mean : 316
7047 tests 2224.530ms Mean : 316
Variance : 0.246micro sec. normalised : 0.078%
Ran : 28051 over 8856.435ms Mean : 315.726micro sec
Total number of tests run : 56188
```

The testCode generated by the tester from the supplied test function

```js
return (function(){
    var now,timer;
    timer = performance;
 
    var i,r,arr = [];
    var xdx = Math.cos(1);
    var xdy = Math.sin(1);

 

    function func0(){
        now = timer.now();

              for(i = 0; i < 1000; i ++){
                  ctx.save();
                  ctx.setTransform(xdx,xdy,-xdy,xdx,0,0);
                  ctx.restore();
              }            
          ;
       return timer.now()-now;
    }
    function func1(){
        now = timer.now();

              for(i = 0; i < 1000; i ++){
                  ctx.setTransform(xdx,xdy,-xdy,xdx,0,0);
                  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
             };
       return timer.now()-now;
    }
    function func2(){
        now = timer.now();

              for(i = 0; i < 1000; i ++){
                  ctx.save();
                  ctx.setTransform(xdx,xdy,-xdy,xdx,0,0);
                  ctx.restore();
              }            
          ;
       return timer.now()-now;
    }
    function func3(){
        now = timer.now();

              for(i = 0; i < 1000; i ++){
                  ctx.setTransform(xdx,xdy,-xdy,xdx,0,0);
                  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
             };
       return timer.now()-now;
    }
    function func4(){
        now = timer.now();

              for(i = 0; i < 1000; i ++){
                  ctx.save();
                  ctx.setTransform(xdx,xdy,-xdy,xdx,0,0);
                  ctx.restore();
              }            
          ;
       return timer.now()-now;
    }
    function func5(){
        now = timer.now();

              for(i = 0; i < 1000; i ++){
                  ctx.setTransform(xdx,xdy,-xdy,xdx,0,0);
                  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
             };
       return timer.now()-now;
    }
    function func6(){
        now = timer.now();

              for(i = 0; i < 1000; i ++){
                  ctx.save();
                  ctx.setTransform(xdx,xdy,-xdy,xdx,0,0);
                  ctx.restore();
              }            
          ;
       return timer.now()-now;
    }
    function func7(){
        now = timer.now();

              for(i = 0; i < 1000; i ++){
                  ctx.setTransform(xdx,xdy,-xdy,xdx,0,0);
                  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
             };
       return timer.now()-now;
    }
var tests = [{ func:func0, result : 0, count : 0, id : 0, name : 'Save restore'},{ func:func1, result : 0, count : 0, id : 1, name : 'Direct restore'},{ func:func2, result : 0, count : 0, id : 0, name : 'Save restore'},{ func:func3, result : 0, count : 0, id : 1, name : 'Direct restore'},{ func:func4, result : 0, count : 0, id : 0, name : 'Save restore'},{ func:func5, result : 0, count : 0, id : 1, name : 'Direct restore'},{ func:func6, result : 0, count : 0, id : 0, name : 'Save restore'},{ func:func7, result : 0, count : 0, id : 1, name : 'Direct restore'},];
const clearResults = function(){tests.forEach(test=>{ test.count = test.result = 0;})}
var testData;
const runTest = function(cycles){
    var testIndex,result,time;
    while(cycles > 0){
        testIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()* tests.length);
        tests[testIndex].result += time = tests[testIndex].func();
        tests[testIndex].count += 1;
        if(time < 0.002){ testData.warning = true; }
        cycles -= 1;
    }
};
return testData = {
   run : runTest,
   warning : false,
   clear : clearResults,
   results : tests,
}
})()
```

> Note that the functions are run randomly to eliminate any bias caused by execution order and optimisation quirkes. That is why all results are statistical analyses of times run.

---

**Unused states compare**

```
Test complete Results.
Calls per sec, % cycle time, % of best time
Save restore : 8130 : 51.91% 100%.
Direct restore : 7531 : 48.09% 92.63%

Total cycles : 1000
Stable cycles : 899 Total.
Tests per cycle : 292
Testing cycles stable for : 800 of 800 cycles 100.00%
Max test variance 0.030%
Test results are good.

List of all test function results. Mean times in micro secs
# calls, total time, mean time
--------------------
Test function : Save restore
31149 tests 3830.600ms Mean : 123
31079 tests 3815.450ms Mean : 123
31321 tests 3858.660ms Mean : 123
31060 tests 3822.630ms Mean : 123
Variance : 0.025micro sec. normalised : 0.020%
Ran : 124609 over 15327.340ms Mean : 123.003micro sec
--------------------
Test function : Direct restore
31173 tests 4131.320ms Mean : 133
31028 tests 4123.105ms Mean : 133
31327 tests 4156.185ms Mean : 133
30986 tests 4122.735ms Mean : 133
Variance : 0.040micro sec. normalised : 0.030%
Ran : 124514 over 16533.345ms Mean : 132.783micro sec
Total number of tests run : 249123
```

*test code for above results*

```js
function saveRestore(){
 sharedFunction = function(){ 
    var i,r,arr = [];
    var xdx = Math.cos(1);
    var xdy = Math.sin(1);
    var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i ++){            gradient.addColorStop(Math.random(),"hsl("+Math.floor(Math.random()*360)+",100%,50%)");
    }
    var col = "Black";
    var col1 = "White";            
 }
  testFunctions = [{
          func:function(){
              ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
              ctx.strokeStyle = col;
              for(i = 0; i < 40; i ++){
                  ctx.save();
                  ctx.fillStyle = col1;
                  ctx.strokeStyle = col1
                  ctx.restore();  // restor style and fill
              }            
          },
          name:"Save restore",
      },{
          func:function(){
              for(i = 0; i < 40; i ++){
                  ctx.fillStyle = col1;
                  ctx.strokeStyle = col1
                  ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
                  ctx.strokeStyle = col;
             }},
          name:"Direct restore",
      }
  ];
  start();
}
```

---

**Use state results**

This when you compare to the above test shows what happens when you use the resulting state (just once the restored state is not used (next test))

```
Test complete Results.
Calls per sec, % cycle time, % of best time
Direct restore : 4390 : 53.30% 100%.
Save restore : 3847 : 46.70% 87.63%

Total cycles : 1000
Stable cycles : 899 Total.
Tests per cycle : 156
Testing cycles stable for : 800 of 800 cycles 100.00%
Max test variance 2.257%
Test results are good.

List of all test function results. Mean times in micro secs
# calls, total time, mean time
--------------------
Test function : Save restore
16289 tests 4271.920ms Mean : 262
16286 tests 4202.980ms Mean : 258
16342 tests 4211.510ms Mean : 258
16291 tests 4262.670ms Mean : 262
Variance : 4.194micro sec. normalised : 1.614%
Ran : 65208 over 16949.080ms Mean : 259.923micro sec
--------------------
Test function : Direct restore
16329 tests 3752.165ms Mean : 230
16388 tests 3669.685ms Mean : 224
16316 tests 3729.565ms Mean : 229
16377 tests 3747.045ms Mean : 229
Variance : 5.141micro sec. normalised : 2.257%
Ran : 65410 over 14898.460ms Mean : 227.770micro sec
Total number of tests run : 130618
```

*Test code for above*

```js
function saveRestore(){
 sharedFunction = function(){ 
    var i,r,arr = [];
    var xdx = Math.cos(1);
    var xdy = Math.sin(1);
    var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i ++){
        gradient.addColorStop(Math.random(),"hsl("+Math.floor(Math.random()*360)+",100%,50%)");
    }
    var col = "Black";
    var col1 = "White";
    

 }
  testFunctions = [{
          func:function(){
              ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
              ctx.strokeStyle = col;
              for(i = 0; i < 40; i ++){
                  ctx.save();
                  ctx.fillStyle = col1;
                  ctx.strokeStyle = col1;
                  ctx.fillRect(0,0,1,1);
                  ctx.restore();  // restor style and fill
              }            
          },
          name:"Save restore",
      },{
          func:function(){
              for(i = 0; i < 40; i ++){
                  ctx.fillStyle = col1;
                  ctx.strokeStyle = col1
                  ctx.fillRect(0,0,1,1);
                  ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
                  ctx.strokeStyle = col;
             }},
          name:"Direct restore",
      }
  ];
  start();
}
```

---

**Use of both new state and restored state test**

Direct restore still ~5% quicker

```
Test complete Results.
Calls per sec, % cycle time, % of best time
Direct restore : 1707 : 51.25% 100%.
Save restore : 1623 : 48.75% 95.11%

Total cycles : 1000
Stable cycles : 899 Total.
Tests per cycle : 60
Testing cycles stable for : 800 of 800 cycles 100.00%
Max test variance 5.881%
Test results are good.

List of all test function results. Mean times in micro secs
# calls, total time, mean time
--------------------
Test function : Save restore
6523 tests 4055.545ms Mean : 622
6660 tests 4043.060ms Mean : 607
6681 tests 4151.470ms Mean : 621
6685 tests 4105.790ms Mean : 614
Variance : 36.231micro sec. normalised : 5.881%
Ran : 26549 over 16355.865ms Mean : 616.063micro sec
--------------------
Test function : Direct restore
6579 tests 3908.045ms Mean : 594
6558 tests 3850.375ms Mean : 587
6547 tests 3815.380ms Mean : 583
6573 tests 3811.335ms Mean : 580
Variance : 28.463micro sec. normalised : 4.858%
Ran : 26257 over 15385.135ms Mean : 585.944micro sec
Total number of tests run : 52806
```

*Code for above*

```js
function saveRestore(){
 sharedFunction = function(){ 
    var i,r,arr = [];
    var xdx = Math.cos(1);
    var xdy = Math.sin(1);
    var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i ++){
        gradient.addColorStop(Math.random(),"hsl("+Math.floor(Math.random()*360)+",100%,50%)");
    }
    var col = "Black";
    var col1 = "White";
    

 }
  testFunctions = [{
          func:function(){
              ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
              ctx.strokeStyle = col;
              for(i = 0; i < 40; i ++){
                  ctx.save();
                  ctx.fillStyle = col1;
                  ctx.strokeStyle = col1;
                  ctx.fillRect(0,0,1,1);
                  ctx.restore();  // restor style and fill
                  ctx.fillRect(0,0,1,1);
              }            
          },
          name:"Save restore",
      },{
          func:function(){
              for(i = 0; i < 40; i ++){
                  ctx.fillStyle = col1;
                  ctx.strokeStyle = col1
                  ctx.fillRect(0,0,1,1);
                  ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
                  ctx.strokeStyle = col;
                  ctx.fillRect(0,0,1,1);
             }},
          name:"Direct restore",
      }
  ];
  start();
}
```

I tried building the gradient in the test but could not get that under the 2ms time limit.

I am out of time so will add more test as I do them. Please do request a test (if it can be done I will show the brief summary results).

Answer (score 0):

I just made a fast profiler and seems that manual takes x4 more time to accomplish... which is the opposite that i've read on internet, anyone has something to contribute? thanks!

Comment: Please also test a simple ctx.rotate(x) + save/restore vs setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0)

Comment: After all testings, in ANY case it seems to be up to x3 to x4 times faster, i don't know why, but even a single property works faster for save/restore, therefore, i'll keep using save/restore in any situation.